# How to create recursive equations

Tags: php, algorithm, laravel

I have a website and I need to let the admin create equations as they wish. This means that they can create equation like:

> Net-profit = Gross-profit - Taxes

and then create another equations:

> Gross-profit = x + y
>
> Taxes = a - b
>
> (where x, y, a and b are constants)

so it is kind of recursive equations. I have no idea how to start, so anything will definitely help.

I am using PHP, and the question is how should the table be organised in order to resolve this dependence in the equations.

Comment: Not much clear what you're going to do..please elaborate more clearly...

Comment: what is the question exactly? you should enter more details about a specific question, and not just tell what you want to do, without proper labels. Should that be C#? javascript? java?!

Comment: To make it clear I am using php, and the question is how to should the table be organised in order to resolve this dependence in the equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a data structure that relates a variable `x` to an expression `y`. Each has a `solved` flag as well.

You can then have an array of these entities, and loop through them to see whether each one is solvable. If something is not solvable then that's fine, just carry on to the next item. Every pass should solve at least one new thing, and if you solve nothing new in a full loop, your set of expressions are not possible to resolve (either because something is not defined, or you have a circular dependency).

The example you've offered is trivially solvable using this approach: four constants and three expressions will be solved in a few iterations (depending on the order you have defined them). For example, the following subset will take two iterations to solve, since the constants are defined after the expression:

```
[First iteration]
Gross-profit = x + y [unsolved]
x = 10 [solved]
y = 20 [solved]

[Second iteration]
Gross-profit = 10 + 20 [solved]
x = 10 [solved]
y = 20 [solved]
```

You'll need an expression evaluator, which would accept an expression (with mathematical operators and precedence brackets) and a set of variable-value pairs, and evaluate the result. You'll need it to throw an exception if the expression is invalid or a variable is not defined. You could achieve this with PHP's `eval()` but that approach is generally thought of as being unsafe.

Code to do this is almost certainly going to be already available in a robust and tested form already. Don't try to write this yourself - search public repositories for a library.

Comment: you mean by expression evaluator, something like string parser that will parse the user input to variables and constants?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Possibly something like [this library](https://github.com/djfm/Evaluator) might help, the description sounds about right. No unit tests though, so more searching would be worthwhile.